# Versiones diferentes de python en entornos distintos

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber si es posible tener instaladas versiones diferentes de Python en entornos virtuales diferentes, y si es así como se puede llevar a cabo.
Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio, también lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. En youtube puedes encontrar varios tutoriales :D

Comment: Si, es posible.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma más simple es crear cada entorno virtual con el comando `python -m venv` en lugar de usar el comando `virtualenv`. De ese modo el entorno virtual que se crea contiene *la misma versión* de python que se usó para crearlo.

Me explico. Imagina que tienes en tu sistema las versiones 3.7 y 3.8 de python. Y vamos a suponer también que cada una de ellas está instalada en una ruta diferente. En ese caso usarías la ruta completa a cada versión particular de python a la hora de crear el entorno virtual. Por ejemplo:

```
$ /ruta/a/la/version/3.7/python -m venv entorno_con_3.7
$ /ruta/a/la/version/3.8/python -m venv entorno_con_3.8
```

Una vez creados estos entornos se activan de la forma habitual, por ejemplo:

```
$ source entorno_con_3.7/bin/activate
```

y el python que estarás usando a partir de ese momento será el 3.7